# MUI DataGrid Server side sorting - additional data to sort model

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I am using MUI DataGrid to display a few datasets on the same page and I would like to enable server side sorting, so that when the user sorts, I would also pass in a string to the handler so I can use it to re-fetch data.

```
    <DataGrid
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      sortingMode="server"
      sortModel={sortModel}
      onSortModelChange={(model) => sortHandler(model)}
    />

...

  const sortHandler = (model: GridSortModel) => {
    console.table(model);
    if (JSON.stringify(model) !== JSON.stringify(sortModel)) {
      setSortModel(model);
    }
  };
```

The `model` in the example above will only expose `field` and `sort` (see below), but **I need at least one more key in that object**:

```
{
    "field": "field1",
    "sort": "asc"
}
```

How can I pass extra data to `sortHandler`, so I can then re fetch the data? Below are the options needed for the API call.

```
const options = {
    ...
    nestedObj: {
      ...
    },
    obj1: {
      name: DYNAMIC_VALUE1,
      order: DYNAMIC_VALUE2,
      rank: DYNAMIC_VALUE3,
    },
    obj2: {
      name: DYNAMIC_VALUE1,
      order: DYNAMIC_VALUE2,
      rank: DYNAMIC_VALUE3,
    },

  };
```

Or is there a better approach? Using `field` is not enough.

Comment: Trouble is, I only have `field` and `sort` in the `GridSortModel`, which makes me thing I should be doing this in a very different way..

Comment: What other key do you need? Are you trying to sort on multiple different fields simultaneously?